# Usefulness of JNI

Tags: java, interop, java-native-interface

I've been a java developer for a couple years and have heard that you can do some pretty useful and powerful things with JNI. I don't know if I just haven't needed to use it or if it isn't terribly relevant to me; but I have not had to touch it at all.

I am wondering what the usefulness of this aspect of Java is. Examples would be great.

Comment: There days Java (-server version) really not noticeably slower than C++ in most of the real usecases, and calling special system API is also pretty specific case. The most real-world usage is when you need to use some library (mathematical or whatever specific), which is written in C/C++ long time ago and still supported, but there is no version of this lib written in Java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is very useful. I can see 2 primary reasons to use JNI (there are likely more).

1. Performance. If you have a piece of code in which the Java Runtime for whatever reason can't cut it performance wise. You can implement that function in native code and call it from Java. This allows you to hand tune the implementation if you *really* need to. This is likely the least common reason though, Java usually performs just fine.
2. Access to OS Specific APIs. This one is a biggie. I've had a case where I needed to do something in Java but also needed access to something that Java simply could not provide. In my case it was UNIX domain sockets. Since (as you can tell by the name) they are UNIX specific, there is no standard Java way to use them. So I made a class that acted like a wrapper around them in C and accessed it with JNI. viola, problem solved.

Comment: Heh ... your 2nd answer reminds me of my assembler class in college -- we had to combine assembler and C functions to finish an assignment. Neat stuff really.

Comment: You can generalize your second point to all external C/C++ libraries you Java software has to depend on.

Answer (score 4):

I  have written an extensive JNI layer for the iSeries to access DB2, user queues, data queues and a few other OS/400 specifics.  Much of our system on the iSeries would have been impossible without JNI.  So, yes, JNI has it's place, and when you need it, you *really* need it.

It's relatively difficult (next to pure Java), but powerful and not horrible.

Also, whenever I am looking at some JNI code, I also consider using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/).

Comment: I don't think I've seen JNA before, wow, I'm such a noob! Heh, thanks :D

Comment: You're welcome; I've never used it because my need for native support was (a) iSeries, and (b) completed and stable years ago... but I'm intrigued by it and will try it if I ever need native access for Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few uses off the top of my head:

1. integration with existing low-level
   (C/C++) APIs that do not have a Java
   counterpart
2. integrating with aspects
   of the system that are not exposed
   through available Java APIs (direct
   hardware access, etc.)

Some might say it can be useful for creating highly-optimized sections of code however with modern JVMs you're getting pretty fast and the complications of using JNI would probably outweigh any performance benefit you might see.

Comment: I agree, but in reality, your reasons 1 and 2 are really the same thing since any thing like direct hardware access is going to be available with a C/C++ API. You can't exactly write drivers in Java, so you'd have to access it the same way C does :-P.

Comment: For #1 I was thinking more about third-party (or legacy) APIs that don't have a Java implementation or even source code (just a library to link to).  For #2 I was thinking more along the lines of your #2, i.e. symbolic link support

Answer (score 1):

There are a few uses for binding to FFMPeg for C-decoding of (damn near any) video/audio format.

There's also JNA, which makes it like you are using the library itself.  This is "easier" from the standpoint that it passes everything to the Java developer to manage, and harder in the sense that you have to figure out the structure mapping and do a lot of grunt work to get all the pointers, etc, to pass correctly.

Comment: I've used JNI to bind a swing app to decode mpegs on a portable way (think linux, x64, windows, os x). It was a mess, but it worked out alright at the end.

Comment: There are JNI bindings for ffmpeg as well.  I used JNA since I needed access to structures that those bindings didn't pass through the JNI layer.

Answer (score 1):

We had an requirement to wrap a new UI around a legacy C application running on Suse Linux. JNI was the perfect tool for the Job.

In general I think JNI is a contradiction to the Java notion of Write Once, Run Anywhere. However there are use cases where JNI can be useful.